# SELECT emails FROM table 1 only if table 2 doesn't have value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting data from a table called "**contacts**" to grab email addresses. It's working just fine but I don't want to echo out any results if the email exists in another table called "**scheduled_emails**". Both tables have a column called "email", so I was thinking I could some how check some kinda comparison. I've been looking into the JOIN to combine rows. Am I wrong?

**My script**

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM contacts WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output emails of users account
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["email"];
  }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `"SELECT ct.email
FROM contacts  ct
LEFT JOIN scheduled_emails se ON se.email= ct.email
WHERE se.email IS NULL AND ct.username= ".$_SESSION["username"]`

Comment: SELECT email FROM contacts WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."' and email not in (select sched.email from scheduled_emails sched)

Comment: Try this `SELECT email FROM contacts WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."' and email not in (select email from scheduled_emails) `

Comment: Thank you very much! Everyone :) I've tried this before - but obviously I did it wrong! I know I asked to not show them... but thinking maybe there is a quick way to show the emails but have them grayed out if they do exist in scheduled_emails?